# Working with deeply nested JSON in Go Lang

Tags: json, go, struct

I have what I would consider a very messy block of JSON, and I want to read and 
modify two values that are deeply nested within (denoted: I want this!) using Go.
Due to the server that I am sending it to,
I cannot change the label names. What makes it especially difficult
for me is that parents have multiple children which are also nested, and since there are so many "value" labels I don't know how to specify which "value" child thatI want to enter.

I got the values in Bash very quickly using this

```
jq ' .value[0].value[1].value[0].value[1].value[0].value="'"$one"'" | '\ '
.value[0].value[1].value[0].value[1].value[1].value="'"$two"'"'
```

I tried a format like this in Go initially, but could not get it working because of the issue where children are all named "value" and I want to go into one other than the first. Unfortunately none of those magic JSON to Go struct were able to handle all of the nesting either.

```
type Bar struct {
    Value struct { // Value[0]
        Value struct {  // Value[1]
            Value struct { // Value[0]
                Value struct { // Value[1]
                    Value struct { // Value[1] or Value[2]
                    }}}}}}
```

This code converts the JSON into a more struct/map friendly form, and prints the whole thing.

```
var foo interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(blob, &foo)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}

m := foo.(map[string]interface{})

// print all
fmt.Println("Loop: ", m)
for k, v := range m {
    fmt.Printf("%v : %v", k, v)
}
```

Here is the JSON that I am storing as a variable

```
var blob = []byte(`{
"tag": "1",
"value": [{
        "tag": "2",
        "value": [{
                "tag": "3",
                "value": [{
                        "tag": "4",
                        "type": "x",
                        "value": "x"
                    }, {
                        "tag": "5",
                        "type": "x",
                        "value": "x"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "tag": "6",
                "value": [{
                        "tag": "7",
                        "value": [{
                                "tag": "8",
                                "type": "x",
                                "value": "x"
                            }, {
                                "tag": "9",
                                "value": [{
                                        "tag": "10",
                                        "type": "x",
                                        "value": "I want this!"
                                    }, {
                                        "tag": "11",
                                        "type": "Thanks for the help mate!",
                                        "value": "I want this!"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "tag": "12",
                "type": "x",
                "value": "x"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "tag": "13",
        "value": [{
                "tag": "14",
                "type": "x",
                "value": "x"
            }, {
                "tag": "15",
                "value": [{
                        "tag": "16",
                        "value": [{
                                "tag": "17",
                                "type": "x",
                                "value": "x"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}`)
```

I would appreciate any help or advice that you could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial attempt didn't work because you used structs where you need a slice of struct (`Value []struct{...}`). But that won't work either, because in some cases the values are slices and in some cases they're strings, which `encoding/json` does not like. Your best bet is one of two options: raw text manipulation, which will probably be quicker but more fragile and error-prone, or decoding as in your second example into a `map[string]interface{}` and doing some gnarly type assertions:

```
var foo map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(blob, &foo)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}

foo["value"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["value"].([]interface{})[1].(map[string]interface{})["value"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["value"].([]interface{})[1].(map[string]interface{})["value"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["value"]
```

Comment: Thank you! That was extremely insightful and helpful. Out of curiosity, do you have some trick for determining the path, or is it just a matter of tediously going through and finding the path for each attribute that I want to get to?

Also, how would I write to that location in foo? When I try to `put := blah` on the right of that long line it produces the error: expected identifier on left side of :=

EDIT: disregard that last setting it equal think. As soon as I typed that I realized that it is just = and not :=

Comment: That depends entirely on the data itself. You might have to do some experimenting to find something that works. Honestly it sounds like you're saddled with a pretty badly structured JSON so tedious may be the only option.